# .each made up attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, each

Ok, I've tried like 5 different revisions and I'm pretty sure my code is just getting worse and worse so I figured I should stop and seek help.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

in the HTML, lets say I create this button:

```
<button border="#ff0000" bg="#0000ff" color="#fff" pad="10px">Click Me</button>
```

As you can see, I made up several attributes and gave them each a value.

I would like to use jquery to select each button, and for each button, cycle through each attribute and take the value and add a real attribute with that value.

for instance, it would see border="#ff0000" and create a border-color: #ff0000: CSS attribute and attach it to that button. It would see the bg="#0000ff" attribute and attach background-color: #0000ff: to that button.

Here's my garbage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").each(function() {  // selects all buttons
        $(this.attr).each(function() {  // selects all attributes within each button
            var attribute = this.parent().attr();  // sets a variable that is equal to the value of the selected made up attribute
            if ($(this).parent().attr("border")) {  // if there is an attribute called border, do this
                $(this).parent().css("border-color", attribute) // give this attribute's parent (the button) this css attribute
            } else if ($(this).attr("bg")) { // rinse and repeat for each attribute I made up
                $(this).parent().css("background-color", attribute)
            } else if ($(this).attr("color")) {
                $(this).parent().css("color", attribute)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please let me know if I'm not making any sense =]

*UPDATE*

The following code works but I just can't help feeling there's an easier/shorter way to code this, since as you can see I'm repeating the same code a lot.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("button").each(function() {
        var bg = $(this).attr("bg");
        var border = $(this).attr("border");
        var color = $(this).attr("color");
        var radius = $(this).attr("radius");
        var pad = $(this).attr("pad");

        if($(this).attr("bg")) {
            $(this).css("background", bg)
        }

        if($(this).attr("border")) {
            $(this).css("border-color", border)
        }

        if($(this).attr("color")) {
            $(this).css("color", color)
        }

        if($(this).attr("radius")) {
            $(this).css("border-radius", radius)
        }

        if($(this).attr("pad")) {
            $(this).css("padding", pad)
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to see that you found a working solution. With regards optimising your answer, there's a few approaches that you could take. I've shared one below, which you might find useful, with some comments summarising what's occurring.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").each(function() {
        // Cache jQuery selectors for each button in an object literal
        var selectors = {
            'background'    : $(this).attr("bg"),
            'border-color'  : $(this).attr("border"),
            'color'         : $(this).attr("color"),
            'border-radius' : $(this).attr("radius"),
            'padding'       : $(this).attr("pad")
        };

        // Iterate over object
        for (var property in selectors) {
            if (selectors.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                // If the current key has a property set
                if(selectors[property]) {
                    // Set CSS property of button using the object key and cached jQuery property
                    $(this).css(property, selectors[property]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<button border="#ff0000" bg="#0000ff" color="#fff" pad="10px">Click Me</button>
<button border="#ff0000" bg="#0000ff" color="#b3d9ff" pad="15px">Click Me</button>
<button border="#ff0000" bg="#0000ff" color="#ffd480" pad="20px">Click Me</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```